# Directing Sublime Text 2 Packages to the correct python installation

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2, environment-variables, sublimetext

I just want to direct a Sublime Text 2 Package (**SublimeREPL**) to the *correct* python installation--at the moment, it's picking up the wrong one.

The story here is familiar to Mac users. The Mac OS comes includes a python install which it uses for various OS stuff for which python is required. Like many others, i prefer not to use this system python (which resides in /System/Library/...) becasue it is usually out of date and of course it's not a good idea to update it--it is a working python install used by the Mac OS, and updating risks causing those OS tasks that depend on that install to break.

But that's the version picked up by the package SublimeREPL:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 25 2011, 05:09:01) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The version i use for development (and which is installed in /Library/Frameworks/ and symlinked to /usr/local/bin) is:

```
@ > python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Sublime 2 Text is picking up the correct version elsewhere, *except* when using the SublimeREPL Package so there must be a setting in one of the config files in that Package that will let me direct SublimeREPL to the correct python.

But i can't find it.

It seems that i have exhausted all plausible options, which, looking through my /Sublime Text 2/Packages/ directory must reside in either:

```
SublimeREPL/

    SublimeREPL (OSX).sublime-settings
    SublimeREPL.sublime-settings
```

*Or*

```
User/

    SublimeREPL.sublime-settings
```

In fact, i added the following each of the *three* JSON files above, with no effect:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin/python2.7:{PATH}"}
}
```

Comment: `default_extend_env` should work as expected. Could you check if there is anything in `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User` (~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/SublimeREPL.sublime-settings)?

Comment: hi--nice work. I use the Node, R, and Python REPLs constantly, in fact. I edited my answer above in light of your comment. As you can see i added the relevant paths to the User/SublimeREPL.sublime-settings but it had no effect (which surprised me). If you know what i did wrong, perhaps put in an Answer & i'll upvote it and also i'll write it up on your Project wiki, 'issue/resolved' i suppose.

Comment: For now please use the workaround that stav provided. Next week I'm planning a small Sublime[REPL|PTY] sprint, and I will definitely check what's going on here :) https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/43

Comment: I was unable to recreate this problem. Setting `"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "/usr/local/bin:{PATH}"` correctly pointed SublimeREPL to the new 2.7.2 version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use `repl_open` you could edit the `cmd` parameter in the config.  I am using Ubuntu and it is located in:

`/home/stav/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`

```
{"command": "repl_open",
"caption": "Python",
"id": "repl_python",
"mnemonic": "p",
"args": {
  "type": "subprocess",
  "encoding": "utf8",
  "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-i", "-u"],
  "cwd": "$file_path",
  "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
  "external_id": "python"
  }
},
```

Comment: brilliant! one upvote and an 'accept' is all i can give; though given that i would have *never* worked that out on my own, your answer is worth a whole lot more. Even the ST2 forum was silent on this one.

Comment: It would be better to set environment variables in the User Settings file, like you said; but this quick fix should do the trick until wuub (or someone) has a look at the SublimeREPL code.  Glad you got er working.

Comment: @doug you could always add a bounty and then award that, if the answer is really worth that much to you.

Comment: Just a note. This file is from the package itself, not the user config. By doing so, the next package upgrade will have you lose this change. In my case, under Mac OS X the section at  `{"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-i", "-u"]}` had `/usr/local/bin/python3` and therefore forcing me to use `python3`. I wonder if there is a way to tell, from the user preference (!), which binary to use instead of only the `$PATH` environment variable. Without deleting Mac OS provided Python of course.

Answer (score 1):

@Steven Almeroth solution did not work for me.

Instead a changed a parameter in the following directory: `packages/Python/Python.sublime-build`

The following code is available there. Simple change the cmd to the directory where your brew of python is located.

```
{
"cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it's simpler to fix a mess around versions patching environment variables specifically for Sublime Text 2 process

The only straight and dumb solution I've found - hack environment variables for Sublime Text 2. This can be done creating .py file with any name in folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/
```

Just add paths you need there and all plugins will use those settings.
See more information in Rob Dodson's blog post: `http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/14/hacking-the-path-variable-in-sublime-text/`

Example .py:

```
import os

LOCAL = '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:'

# Sublime's default path is
# /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
os.environ['PATH'] += ':'
os.environ['PATH'] += LOCAL

print 'PATH = ' + os.environ['PATH']
```