# ImportError when trying to import python module in SublimeText2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm new to SublimeText2. So far I have found it excellent, but I just came across a problem I did not manage to solve. I'm trying to import a Python module, *mechanize*, into my script. However, whenever a run it (just the *import mechanize* line), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gabrielbianconi/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mechanize
ImportError: No module named mechanize
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

However, when I run this line in Terminal, it works perfectly:

```
gb-air:~ gabrielbianconi$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mechanize
>>>
```

I guess this is a problem with ST2. I saw that ST2 on Mac uses the system's python, so I don't see why it doesn't recognize the module.

Thank you very much.

Edit: I'm on OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: hope it will help : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239839/sublime-text2-import-error-no-module-named-gnuplot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. ST2 was not using the same python as the Terminal. For anyone having the same mistake, you can solve this by selecting: Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Browser Packages... Then go into 'Python' folder and open 'Python.sublime_build'. Now edit the 'cmd' parameter to match your desired Python path. For me (using MacPorts), the result was:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Comment: +1, excellent. i had a similar problem w/ getting the python REPL to locate and use the correct python install, even ST2 was doing this correctly except for REPL. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712390/directing-sublime-text-2-packages-to-the-correct-python-installation)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code helped me (enter in in the linux terminal):

```
echo "export PATH=~/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

([source](https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/))