# unexplained entry appears when i run 'ls' command in one of my Git repositories

Tags: python, package

When i 'cd' into one of my GIT repositories from terminal and run the ls command i can see two entries. One of them i expect to see as it is the python file i created but i also see an entry '=3.4.0' as well. What is this entry? Is appears to be a version number of somesort. Can someone shed light on this?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605646/importerror-when-trying-to-import-python-module-in-sublimetext2)?

Comment: im sorry? what didnt i see?

Comment: oh whoops i see now. Sorry im still a newby with these sites

Comment: Please do not post terminal output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Comment: It's just another file you appear to have accidentally created.

Comment: if i use vim to open it i get the output Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.5.2.post1)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf) (39.0.1)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: six>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf) (1.11.0

Comment: okay ill just delete this file. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you ran something like the following at the command line

```
$ pip install protobuf>=3.4.0
```

But the `>` character in the shell is the output redirection operator, so your shell reads this as "run `pip install protobuf` and pipe its standard output to a file named `=3.4.0`"

In the future, when trying to pip install packages with some version specifier I recommend putting it in quotes to prevent any problems like this:

```
$ pip install 'protobuf>=3.4.0'
```

Comment: well done. I actually remember doing exactly that. Thanks for that.

Comment: I have done the same enough times myself that I habitually put quotes around arguments to pip even if I'm not explicitly using a version specifier :)

Comment: Ive been used to using the '|' symbol for piping i forgot about the '>' symbol. What is the difference between them?

Comment: `|` pipes the standard output from one program to the standard input of another program.  `>` just pipes directly to a file.