# Error running Python 3 from Sublime Text, works in IDLE

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2

I have:

```
def confirm_title(title):
    print("Is '", title, "' correct?", sep='')
    confirmation = input("Y = yes N = no: ")
    return confirmation
```

in sublime text 2 and ran it using the following command:

> Tools -> Build System -> (choose) Python
>   <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>  (OSX)

The sublime text console gave me the following error:

```
File "/Users/robert/Desktop/Python/ex_1.py", line 69
    print("Is '", title, "' correct?", sep='')
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 3.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/robert/Desktop/Python/ex_1.py"]
[dir: /Users/robert/Desktop/Python]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Now if I ran this on the python IDLE 3.4 it works just fine. Why is it that in sublime text it doesn't? Is it because it's using some other version of python that was preinstalled or what?

Comment: whats the result when you remove `sep=''`?  Double check that you are using the correct python version (http://theshank.tumblr.com/post/26276497763/sublime-text-how-to-change-the-version-of-python-that)

Comment: Is the python on your path the same version as the one used in IDLE?

Comment: try do something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712390/directing-sublime-text-2-packages-to-the-correct-python-installation?rq=1

Comment: you are running it with python2 instead of python3

Comment: I think that is the problem. It using the old preinstalled mac 2.7 version instead of the new downloaded 3.4 version. How do I change the path of where it looks for the interpreter 3.4?

Comment: @robertrocha, I think that the link I provided above details that - does it not? (I honestly didn't read the entire tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

This is SyntaxError is triggrered because you are using Python 2.x in Sublime.

You can confirm this by e.g.,

by simple execute a

```
print "hello world"
```

If this works, you can be sure that you are not using Python 3, but Python 2. Or simply import

```
from platform import python_version
print python_version
```

Python 2 supports the call of `print` as a function in general, but the result gets ugly when you are trying to print a tuple.

```
print 'Hello, World!'
print('Hello, World!')

Python 2.7.6
Hello, World!
Hello, World!


print 'Python', python_version()
print('a', 'b')
print 'a', 'b'

Python 2.7.6
('a', 'b')
a b
```

And you can't use the `end` parameter in Python 2. If you want to print on the same line, you can use this:

```
print "text", ; print 'print more text on the same line'

text print more text on the same line
```